# apache camel hazelcast getting custom header

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to get the header or property which i set before calling hazelcast but i couldn't able to get the custom header which i set.

```
<route>
<from uri=""/>
<setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastObjectId">
    <constant>123</constant>
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastOperationType">
    <constant>put</constant>
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="test">
    <constant>test</constant>
</setHeader>
<setProperty propertyName="test">
    <constant>test</constant>
</setProperty>
<to uri="hazelcast:map:testMap"/>
</route>
```

When i trying to retrieve my custom header or property couldn't able to get that

```
<route>
<from uri="hazelcast:map:testMap"/>
<log message = "printing:::: ${in.header.test} and ${property[test]}"/>
<to uri=""/>
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The camel-hazelcast component is only for storing the message body, not message headers.